# How do I test for when someone kills all of the zombies in an area?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to make a minecraft map in windows 10 edition but I can't get the setbock command to work if all of the mobs in the area have been killed.

Comment: What do you mean all the mobs in an "area"? Could you test and see if there are no zombies in a radius from a block and then run commands, or do you have to test something else?

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is that you can do a command `testfor` this will test for entities:

```
/testfor @e[type=zombie]
```

This will test for all currently loaded zombies

```
 /testfor @e[type=zombie,(r for PE, distance for PC)=20]
```

This will test for all zombies within a 20 block radius. Radius is building that many blocks off the sides and connecting them to a cube. Thus displaying radius. Than have a comparator coming out of the command block and redstone repeater followed by a solid block with a redstone torch

Comment: As the question states, the post is for bedrock edition. Specifying that the selector `r` should be substituted with `distance` for java edition is not required, since `/testfor` has been replaced with `/execute` in the Java edition.

Comment: Also, please don't use `testfor` even in versions of Minecraft that support it unless you really know what you're doing.  It should be considered to be deprecated, as its utility is almost entirely dependent on conditional command blocks, which can't be used directly in functions.  There are almost always better ways to solve a problem by using something other than `testfor`.